# Is the `totalSupply` method necessary?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

If you have a public variable like this:

> uint256 public totalSupply;

Is it necessary to also include a `totalSupply` method to a standard ERC20 contract?

I know there is a getter that Solidity generates for public vars.

Comment: The ERC20 standard states that a method which returns the total supply is required. It doesn't state how this method should be provided, nor does it care about the fact that Solidity generates getters for public variable. In fact, this statement is not even correct. It is the **Solidity Compiler** (`solc`) which generates getter methods, and technically speaking, those who implemented it could have chosen not to do so (unless it's in the language standard, but in either case, it has nothing to do with the ERC20 standard).

Comment: In any case, to answer your question in a practical manner: In OpenZeppelin v1.x, this variable was public, and a getter method was not necessary. As of v2, this variable is private, and a getter method is provided explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary. The Erc20 is an interface standard. It means that in order to have a compliance, your SM must permit a call to that method, namely totalSupply(), which must return an uint256 as described.

Due to a known compiler limitation (as per 0.4.25 for sure, at the moment I did not tested the stable 0.5.0 for this aspect),  Solidity is not able to discover the overloaded methods if the overloading function is a getter automatically created by itself, even if it does exist. At the moment the alternatives are:

1) to have a public variable with the prescribed name and to be compliant by the public getter it implies;

2) to have a variable with a different name (_totalSupply is a typical choice) and to write an explicit getter with the prescribed name.

Both of those approach are currently present in the recommended practice repositories (Consensys and Openzeppelin and so on).

In short: in order to be fully compliant, a compliant method has to be available, it is up to you to choose which way to use in order to assure this.